# How can I add an extra item to an existing item in a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jtabbedpane

I've been trying to avoid to ask a question and solve this myself, but I can't seem to solve this problem. I made it work but not exactly how I wanted it.

I have an Inventory program I'm working on, and I already have some items added and divided in different tabs. I'm supposed to add new items directly from the program. I did this by adding JOptionPane, and once the item is added, it adds an extra tab panel, but what I want is the item to be added in the selected tab panel.

Here is an image of the program I have so far:

[image]

I'm sorry if it looks like a mess, I'm still working on it, and I'm still trying to add the new item to the selected tab panel, not by adding an extra tab panel.

Comment: You are telling it to add a new tab by saying `tabs.addTab(...)`. If you want to add to the currently selected tab, you have to get the currently selected tab and add to it. You can get it with the command `tabs.getTabComponentAt(tabs.getModel().getSelectedIndex());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
tabs.addTab("New Item", null, newItemPanel, "New item panel");
```

With

```
JPanel selectedTab = (JPanel) tabs.getSelectedComponent();
selectedTab.add(newItemPanel);
selectedTab.revalidate();
```

You'll still have to fix the layout and appearance of the new panel, but this will add it to the current tab.

Comment: That really helped thanks. I'll fix it, no problem ^w^ Thank you so much!!